# Error in Go Compilation : cannot use new(SimpleChaincode)

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

While compiling an application of the 'DemoChainCode' from IBM Bluemix docs I'm continously getting this error :

`.\Asgn5.go:28: cannot use new(SimpleChaincode) (type *SimpleChaincode) as type s him.Chaincode in argument to shim.Start:
  *SimpleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Initmethod)
  have Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)
  want Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) ([]byte, error)`

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Please provide more information ( code ).

Comment: if `SimpleChaincode`  is a custom struct implement ` Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) ([]byte, error)` function

Answer (score 0):

I think this guidance from the hyperledger folks should help:

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/master/docs/setup.md#hyperledger-fabric

The issue is that there are mutually incompatible releases of hyperledger.

I think (!) for Bluemix, you will need v0.5

Comment: Thank you DazWilkin. I will check my Fabric version and try again.